# Passing an uninitialised array to a method expecting a non-nullable IEnumerable doesn't cause a compilation warning or error

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

In C# 8 with nullable reference types enabled, why does the following not raise a compiler warning or error?

```
var strings = new string[1];
    
LogList(strings);
    
public void LogList(IEnumerable<string> strings) {
    foreach(var s in strings) {
        Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    }
}
```

I was expecting a compiler warning or error because the array has uninitialised elements, whilst `String` in `IEnumerable<String>` is non-nullable. Instead I get a NullReferenceException at runtime when `s.ToString()` is called.

If I indicate that the array elements are nullable, `string?[]`, or use a collection with a nullable string, `List<string?>` then the compiler warns me about passing this to `LogList` which is expecting a (not null) IEnumerable of not null strings. Why is a similar warning not generated for the above code sample?

I have looked through a number of questions on SO about nullable reference types but none answer this question specifically.

*(Code tested in LINQPad 6.9.15)*

Comment: There are a number of exceptions to the nullable rules involving initialization, all surrounding existing semantics for things like arrays and structs, which have implicit initialization. See duplicate, and of course the referenced article, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/. The short version: the C# language designers felt that warning on these scenarios would generate too many false-positives, so they intentionally exclude them from analysis. You declared your array as having non-nullable elements, and the compiler believed you. So no warning.

Answer (score 0):

In this code `var strings = new String[1];`, `strings` is not null but a valid `IEnumerable<string>` object in which the first entry is null. So to make `strings` null, you can do like this `string[] strings = null;`.

Then when you run the application by enabling nullable reference type, the compiler wont throw exception rather will raise warning. (as like in 1st screenshot).

To get that as error, Add the below entries to your .csproj file inside `<PropertyGroup>`

```
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <WarningsAsErrors>CS8600;CS8602;CS8603</WarningsAsErrors>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mentioned "a valid IEnumerable<string> object in which the first entry is null" but I expected this to only be valid as IEnumerable<string?>. Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: okk, this is generics, generics are special case.

Comment: Also `String[]` does not implement `IEnumerable<string?>`

Comment: According to this article arrays do implement IEnumerable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#array-overview - "Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array. Since this type implements IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>, you can use foreach iteration on all arrays in C#"

Comment: Generics type are specials as they can represent value types (struct) and references types (class). This means you cannot use the T? type to represent a nullable type as it would conflict with the existing Nullable<T> when the generic is a value type.

Comment: I'm not following - T cannot be both a reference and value type so if T were a reference, how would T? conflict with Nullable<T> which is used for value types only? Are you able to update your answer with regard to generics being a special case? Thanks

Comment: Please check this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/#the-issue-with-t